# Ghost position keyframes in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I have an animation in After Effects where I am animating a slider to move up and down at certain points. The slider should be mainly stationary, but moves occasionally in line with other actions on the project.

[image]

What I am finding though, is the slider is moving a small amount even when the keyframes are set such that it should be static. E.g. the following two keyframes are the same (Y position = 524.6) but if I move the marker in between, you'll see the value deviates from this. (As a result the slider moves.)

1st Keyframe (Y Position = 524.6):
[image: 1st Keyframe]

2nd Keyframe (Y Position = 524.6):
[image: 2nd Keyframe]

In between (Y position varies, up to 525.4):
[image: In between]

This is driving me nuts! As far as I can see the anchor point does not move, so I don't understand why this should happen.

Comment: Do you have a splined move between the keyframes?

Comment: What is a splined move? ;-) (Possibly - how do I tell?)

Comment: I can't give you the AE settings but when you have two position keyframes you can choose to move between them linearly or with a curve / easing / spline to smooth the motion. Sometimes even when the positions are the same, the tension of the spline results in a bump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of spatial interpolation.  Here's a previous answer:

[Object moving to a position I didn't specify](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14687/object-moving-to-a-position-i-didnt-specify/14697#14697)